# Delete entry in Join Table automatically when deleting entry in main table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a `WorkpackageEntity` that contains an array of `TaskEntity` like such:

In our `WorkpackageEntity`:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = TaskEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<TaskEntity> tasks;
```

In our `TaskEntity`:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = WorkpackageEntity.class)
private WorkpackageEntity wp;
```

Therefore a join table is automatically created called `workpackage_tasks` that contains the ID of both entities that are linked.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I delete a `TaskEntity` from my `task` table, it should also automatically delete the corresponding entry in the `worpackage_tasks` table.

So far it tries to delete the entry in `task` and throws me the following (obvious) error:

> ERROR: update or delete on table "task" violates foreign key constraint "fknd9vbaspv4un3lkr420fbe78j" on table "workpackage_tasks"
>
> Detail: Key (task_id)=(8) is still referenced from table "workpackage_tasks".

Comment: Declare the FK constraint with `on delete cascade`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand

Comment: `create table workpackage_tasks (task_id integer, workpackage_id integer, foreign key (task_id) referencs tasks (id) ON DELETE CASCADE, foreign key (workpackage_id) references workpackage (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)`

Comment: Can that be done via hibernate as it automatically generates my table?

Comment: Kinda, if you use `cascade="delete"` in your collection, but this will be handled by Hibernate (it will send multiple `delete` statements), not database. I think hibernate does not support cascading by database. You can read about it a bit more [jboss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html) and [some blog with examples](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

Comment: @Chris What prevent you of using a traditional bidirectional association making your TaskEntity Owning side of your relation?? What is your purpose making WorkpackageEntity owning side of the relation which is by the way unusual.